# MySQL IN() clause multiple returns

Tags: mysql

I have a special data environment where I need to be returned data in a certain way to populate a table.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT 
  bs_id, 
  IF(bs_board = 0, 'All Boards', (SELECT b_name FROM certboards WHERE b_id IN (REPLACE(bs_board, ';', ',')))) AS board 
FROM boardsubs
```

As you can see I have an `if` statement then a special subselect.

The reason I have this is that the field `bs_board` is a `varchar` field containing multiple row IDs like so:

```
1;2;6;17
```

So, the query like it is works fine, but it only returns the first matched `b_name`. I need it to return all matches.  For instance in this was `1;2` it should return two boards `Board 1` and `Board 2` in the same column. Later I can deal with adding a `<br>` in between each result.

But the problem I am dealing with is that it has to come back in a single column both name, or all names since the field can contain as many as the original editor selected.

Comment: `bs_board = 0` did you mean `bs_board = '0'`?

Comment: If you can, please normalize the table. You should not have multiple values in a single column.

Comment: @njk I cannot change the column type, it will ALWAYS stay as a `varchar` with values like so `1;2;3`, period. That is why I posted here to find if there was a way to parse the way it is now. And yes I should have multiple values, it is perfectly able to work that way, thank you.

Comment: @jfreak53 "It works" doesn't mean it's a wise idea.  Your question amounts to, "How do I normalize my database on the fly every time I need to run this query?"  It's perfectly reasonable for us to ask, "Can't you just normalize the schema and be done with it?"

Comment: @jfreak53 You should **not** have multiple values in a single column, just because *it is perfectly able to work that way*. If you don't feel like using the principles of a relational DBMS, then perhaps you shouldn't be using one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work the way you're thinking it will work.

Let's say `bs_board` is `'1;2;3'`

In your query, `REPLACE(bs_board, ';', ',')` will resolve to `'1,2,3'`, which is a single literal string.  This makes your final subquery:

```
SELECT b_name FROM certboards WHERE b_id IN ('1,2,3')
```

which is equivalent to:

```
SELECT b_name FROM certboards WHERE b_id = '1,2,3'
```

The most correct solution to the problem is to [normalize your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Non-first_normal_form_.28NF.C2.B2_or_N1NF.29).  Your current system or storing multiple values in a single field is exactly what you should never do with an RDBMS, and this is exactly why.  The database is not designed to handle this kind of field.  You *should* have a separate table with one row for each `bs_board`, and then `JOIN` the tables.

There are no good solutions to this problem.  It's a fundamental schema design flaw.  The easiest way around it is to fix it with application logic.  First you run:

```
SELECT bs_id, bs_board FROM boardsubs
```

From there you parse the `bs_board` field in your application logic and build the actual query you want to run:

```
SELECT bs_id, 
  IF(bs_board = 0, 'All Boards', (SELECT b_name FROM certboards WHERE b_id IN (<InsertedStringHere>) AS board 
FROM boardsubs
```

There are other ways around the problem, but you will have problems with sorting order, matching, and numerous other problems.  The best solution is to add a table and move this multi-valued field to that table.

Answer (score 1):

The `b_id IN (REPLACE(bs_board, ';', ','))` will result in `b_id IN ('1,2,6,7')` which is different from `b_id IN (1,2,6,7)` which is what you are looking for.

To make it work either parse the string before doing the query, or use prepared statements.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: "b_id IN ('1,2,6,7')" compares b_id to single string value '1,2,6,7' whereas "b_id IN (1,2,6,7)" compares b_id to each 4 value in the set.

Comment: That's my point, it has to stay that way. How do I parse the values out, that is my problem I can't figure out how to convert it from parsing it into `'1,2,3'` to parse it as `1,2,3`